# PostgreSQL Job Scheduling: Creating Schedule Backup using Bat File

Tags: windows, postgresql, batch-file

I tried creating backup using batch file.

backup.bat

```
@echo off
set BACKUPDIR="C:\Users\Name\Documents\DBBackup"
set PGHOST="localhost"
set PGUSER="postgres"
set PGBIN="C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin"

for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%i in ("%date%") do 
(
 set dow=%%i
 set month=%%j
 set day=%%k
 set year=%%l
)

for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=: " %%i in ("%time%") do 
(
 set hh=%%i
 set nn=%%j
)
%PGBIN%pg_dump -h %PGHOST% -U %PGUSER% -f %BACKUPDIR%fullpgbackup-%year%%day%%month%.backup
```

When i tried to run this in command line, I encountered error:

**'pg_dump' is not recognized as an internal or external command.**

Maybe thats the reason why i wasn't able to execute the Job schedule well.

Please Im new at batch file and this creation of this kind of backup.

Comment: maybe $PGBIN$\pg_dump.exe ?..

Comment: i tried and execute in command line, no error shows but not creating backup either. what's wrong with this? :(

Comment: Change the `set` syntax to `set "VAR=Value"` (note the moved `"`), so the quotation marks do not become part of the value;then when concatenating, use `"%VAR%\something"`, so quotation marks around the entire path and a backslash inserted (Windows excuses if you put two consecutive backslashes but you need one at least)...

Comment: Scheduled backup is very inferior to replication

Comment: Check The of `pg_dump`