# PostgreSQL: Unable to Restore .backup using pgAdmin III Restore

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, database-restore

In reference to this question:

[PostgreSQL Job Scheduling: Creating Schedule Backup using Bat File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38782752/postgresql-job-scheduling-creating-schedule-backup-using-bat-file)

It made me successful to have a back-up for my database.

Filename: Database_backup.backup

However, using PgAdmin III using Restore selection, i wasn't able to restore it, it shows Error:

> C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\pg_restore.exe --host localhost
>   --port 5432 --username "postgres" --dbname "db_name" --no-password  --list "C:\Users\Name\Documents\Backup_20160805.backup"
>   pg_restore: [archiver] input file appears to be a text format dump.
>   Please use psql.

What I am missing here?

Is it in Backup?

Again, I need your guidance here.

Thanks so much.

---

Answer (score 2):

`pg_dump`, which is called by pgAdmin III to perform backups, can create them in four formats:

- *plain*: SQL commands
- *custom*: compressed proprietary binary format
- *directory*: one backup file per table
- *tar*: like "directory", but as a `tar` archive

There is a "format" dropdown in pgAdmin III that lets you select the format.

To restore a plain format dump, you'll have to execute the SQL script with pgAdmin III or `psql`.

For the other three formats, you use `pg_restore`, which is internally called by pgAdmin III's "restore" functionality.

So you took a plain format dump, which causes the reported error with `pg_restore`. Execute it as a SQL script instead!

Comment: Hi @Laurez Albe, thanks for the suggestion. But what i have backup here is thru batch file. Please see above-mentioned link how to create backup. I'm having issues when i use it to restore function in pgAdmin III.

Comment: That's what I say. Either make the dump as you do now and restore by executing it as SQL script, or take the dump in a different format and restore it the way you are trying to do now. That script you're using isn't immutable. It contains a call to `pg_dump`. If you want *custom* format, just add the `-Fc`to it.